# Initialize array of structs - c code error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struc called player, and I need to make an array of MAX players, so I based on the following page [C - initialize array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173518/c-initialize-array-of-structs), like so:

```
DEFINE MAX 200

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
} Player;

Player* PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));
```

Problem is I keep getting the following error

```
error: expected expression before ‘=’ token
error: initializer element is not constant
```

Base code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX = 200;

typedef struct
{
    int ID;
} Player;

Player *PlayerList;

int start()
{
    PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is `PlayerList` a defined type, which you're also trying to use as a variable?  What is `MAX` defined as?

Comment: MAX is a defined number.

Comment: Please post short but complete examples - other people should be able to paste your code listing to a file and compile it without changes (or fail to compile, but with exactly the same errors).

Comment: `#define MAX = 200;` ----> `#define MAX 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use only constant for initialization in old type 'C'.

rewrite

```
Player* PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));
```

to

```
Player* PlayerList;
PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));
```

Add E.G.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 200

typedef struct
{
   int ID;
} Player;

Player* PlayerList=NULL;

int main(void){
    PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I make this global some how?

Comment: @Morki note: You could not write executable statements outside a function.

Comment: Can I do something like static PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));

Comment: inside a function, yes. But it's not the same thing.

Comment: @Morki I think that you cannot even static, but do not you mean `C++`?  　It is possible if `C++` is an explicit cast is required in that case.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to free one player? free(PlayerList[2])

Comment: @Morki it is not possible to `free` other than the start address in the space allocated by the `malloc`, it can be released in case `realloc` the last element. Should be replaced by yourself if this is not the case.

Comment: So it's not possible to deallocate/remove a player?

Comment: @Morki It isn't possible to be freed using `free` some elements(e.g.`free(PlayerList[2])`).

Comment: So the only way would be to do something like PlayerList[2].ID = NULL, and then reuse it later. Then wait until I want to free everything and call free(PlayerList)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `malloc()` from outside of any function. Just declare `Player* PlayerList;`, and let one of the first things you do in `main()` be `PlayerList = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Player));`.

Comment: I see. But I need PlayerList to be a global, how would do that.

Comment: You can *declare* PlayerList outside of any function, but using a function call (`malloc()`) to initialize it, that can only be done in a context where function calls are valid.

Comment: You need to show your full code, then. complete, compilable, minimal code sample.

Comment: And there's the difference! `#define MAX = 200;` is not the same as `#define MAX 200`. remember, `#define` is a token substitution performed by a preprocessor. By the time the compiler tries to actually compile your code, you're now left with `PlayerList = malloc(= 200; * sizeof(Player));`, which I'm sure you'll agree is nonsensical.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to free one player?
free(PlayerList[2])

Comment: Can't do that. You can only `free()` exactly the things you get from `malloc()`. You could set PlayerList[2] to some flag value indicating that it's invalid, or you could switch to an entirely different model, and use a linked link to keep your players in.

Comment: So the only way would be to do something like PlayerList[2].ID = NULL, and then reuse it later. Then wait until I want to free everything and call free(PlayerList)?

Comment: yeah, except for the NULL part. NULL is a pointer. Just use 0, or -1.